# C++ destructor won't free properly

Tags: c++, class, valgrind, destructor

i'm trying to free an apartment class object properly, but valgrind
says "invalid free, address...is on thread 1's stack"
Here's the code:
I'll be very grateful if you could point to my mistakes.

```
class Apartment{
public:
enum SquareType {EMPTY, WALL, NUM_SQUARE_TYPES};
class ApartmentException : public std::exception {};
class IllegalArgException : public ApartmentException {};
class OutOfApartmentBoundsException : public ApartmentException {};

int length;
int width;
int price;
SquareType** squares;

Apartment (SquareType** squares, int length, int width, int price);
Apartment (const Apartment& apartment);
Apartment& operator=(const Apartment& apartment);
~Apartment();
};

Apartment::Apartment (SquareType** squares=NULL, int length=0, int width=0, int price=0){
    this->price=price;
    this->length=length;
    this->width=width;

    this->squares = new SquareType*[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length ; i++){
        this->squares[i]= new SquareType[width];
    }
    this->squares = squares;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++){

            this->squares[i][j] = squares[i][j];
        }
    }
}
Apartment::Apartment (const Apartment& apartment):length(apartment.length),
                    width(apartment.width),price(apartment.price),squares(apartment.squares){

    for(int i=0; i<apartment.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<apartment.width; j++){
            squares[i][j] = apartment.squares[i][j];
        }
    }

}
Apartment& Apartment::operator=(const Apartment& apartment){

    if(this == &apartment){
        return *this;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        delete [] squares[i];
    }
    delete [] squares;

    squares = new SquareType*[apartment.length];

    for(int i=0; i<apartment.length ; i++){
        squares[i]= new SquareType[apartment.width];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<apartment.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<apartment.width; j++){
            squares[i][j] = apartment.squares[i][j];
        }
    }
    price=apartment.price;
    length=apartment.length;
    width=apartment.width;
    return *this;
}
Apartment::~Apartment(){
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        delete [] squares[i];
    }
    delete [] squares;
}
```

that's the main:

```
int main(){

    Apartment::SquareType square1[5]={Apartment::WALL};
    Apartment::SquareType square2[5]={Apartment::WALL};
    Apartment::SquareType square3[5]={Apartment::WALL};
    Apartment::SquareType square4[5]={Apartment::WALL};

    Apartment::SquareType* squares[4]={square1,square2,square3,square4};
    Apartment::SquareType* Squares[3]={square1,square2,square3};

Apartment ap(squares,4,5,0);
Apartment ap2(Squares,3,5,50);

return 0;

}
```

and that's the valgrind output:[valg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM33E.jpg)

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, why not vector of vectors? In c-tor you first create whole 2D areay and then: this->squares = squares;. This causes memory leaks for sure

Answer (score 0):

Your copy constructor must copy the contents of `squares` as you did in the assignment operator instead of just assigning the address in `apartment.squares`.

Comment: I did, i've copied the whole content, in that nested for loop

Comment: No, you didn't. You just performed assignment between the same memory region. Create new buffer for new object first.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the copy constructor. You (correctly) have this:

```
    this->squares = new SquareType*[length];
```

but then you shortly thereafter have this:

```
    this->squares = squares;
```

causing both a memory leak and potentially a dangling pointer.

More broadly:

- You shouldn't be dealing so heavily in `new`. Rather, you should use the standard library's abstractions; `std::vector` seems well-suited to your case, and in fact would let you completely eliminate the destructor.
- You should take a look at "[What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)"; it's a way to make these core functions simpler and more robust.

Comment: Where `this->squares = new SquareType*[length];` is not a copy constructor, but the constructor also seems wrong...

Comment: Thanks , but i'd like to learn how to do this right with simple arrays first. What's the solution to the memory leaks you've mentioned?  Lose this assignment and just copy the contents ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issue with your `Apartment` constructor overwriting the pointer returned from `new[]`, your copy constructor should do what's in your assignment operator.  Instead, you're just assigning the pointer and not copying the data (you're doing a *shallow* copy, and not a *deep* copy).

```
Apartment::Apartment(const Apartment& rhs) : price(rhs.price), length(rhs.length), width(rhs.width), squares(new SquareType*[rhs.length])
{
    for(int i=0; i<rhs.length ; i++)
       squares[i]= new SquareType[rhs.width];

    for(int i=0; i<rhs.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<rhs.width; j++)
            squares[i][j] = rhs.squares[i][j];
    }
}
```

Once you have this, there is no need for your assignment operator to duplicate this same code.  All your assignment operator could do is this:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
Apartment& Apartment::operator=(const Apartment& rhs)
{
   Apartment temp(rhs);
   std::swap(temp.price, price);
   std::swap(temp.length, length);
   std::swap(temp.width, width);
   std::swap(temp.squares, squares);
   return *this;
}
```

This uses the `copy / swap` idiom.

But overall, it is easy to break your code even with these changes.  What if a NULL is passed as `squares` in the `Apartment` constructor, and length and/or width are greater than 0?  You will be assigning to your `squares`  from the passed in NULL pointer, causing undefined behavior.

It would be better if you resorted to using containers such as `std::vector` that knows their size automatically without the client having to give you this information explicitly.

Comment: As I'm certain there is a cunning reason for this, why did you not pass `rhs` by value and use it instead of `temp`?

Comment: You could do it that way -- just wanted the assignment operator signature to look more like the OP's.

Comment: Rats. I was hoping there was some sneaky compiler optimization I'd been missing out on.